# What is the name of the implicit variable in a java while loop?

Tags: java, perl, while-loop

In Perl you can write something like

```
while(!eof){  
    doSomething(x,y);  
    print $_;  
}
```

and the second statement prints out the iteration the loop is up to using `$_`, the name of the invisible variable Perl uses to iterate through the loop. What is the name of that variable in Java?

I realise that you can accomplish the same thing by declaring a variable outside the loop and incrementing it, but this way is definitely more elegant if anyone knows how to do it.

Comment: As far as I know there is no such implicit counter variable in java.

Comment: You used the word "elegant" in a post about Java; that's unusual, unless it's a negation.

Comment: Yeah, I did, but the word was referring to perl.

Comment: Well in his defense: It was a sentence about perl, without comments and written by an unknown person - you pretty much have to guess what the hell's going on.

Comment: There is nothing implicit in that code. Nothing sets `$_`.

Comment: @ikegami: Couldn't `doSomething` set it?

Comment: @musiKk, Perhaps, but that doesn't make it implicit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no implicit variable in Java as in Perl. You just have to be more *explicit* in Java...

Answer (score 4):

There is no such concept in Java.

In Groovy, at least you get an `it` variable set on the functional methods.

```
myList = [1,2,3];
myList.each {
   println it
}
```

or to read a file, like in your example...

```
new File('test.txt').eachLine {
   println it
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are mistaken; perl does not implicitly do anything with $_ in the while loop you show.

You are either thinking of for/foreach loops, where $_ is the default iteration variable if you do not specify one, or of the special case of a while with the expression being a readline or glob operation, where an assignment to `$_` is added for you.

Comment: While technically correct, IMHO this should be a comment and not answer. It doesn't address the meat of the Q, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

you can even be more *implicit*:

```
foreach (<LINE>){  
    doSomething(x,y);  
    print;   #If you don't specify what to print, it prints "$_"
}
```

However, what was once acceptable is no longer acceptable. It's much like not using `use strict` and `use warnings` in your code. Not using these pragmas allowed you to do so many *interesting* things. Things that you might not have intended to do and things that make your code really hard to understand.

Almost all Perl programmers no longer use the implicit `$_` and `@_` because it's just makes your code all that more difficult to understand and can be a cause errors (like assuming that `while` also uses an implicit `$_` ;-) ).

Java (and most languages) don't have such a default variable because it's not really all that good an idea. Good Perl ideas like CPAN and expanded regular expressions have now been copied in other languages. Things like default variables have not.

Using this stuff can be fun -- like a secret decoder ring that allowed you to know who's a real Perl hacker and who isn't. It's fun to read through all that obfuscated Perl code and see who really understands the inner workings of Perl.

However, it has also given developers in other languages the proof they need that Perl was hopelessly sloppy and impossible to understand. And, as a result, Perl has suffered in general acceptance.